# UI design guidelines of Android - where to be found?

Tags: android, user-interface, ui-design

I'd like to develop apps for Android after 2 years of developing iPhone apps. First of all, I'm not a programmer. I'm a UI designer and usability engineer with basic knowledge of app programming. I have a colleague doing the part of the programmer. So my first look into the documents on developer.android.com titled "UI design" resultet in surprise. No real design guidelines, just clutter about coding, no concrete hints how apps have to look like what you are expecting when you read "UI Design". OK - Android is a very open system for many different hardware types - maybe a little bit hard to give advices that fit for all systems - but not impossible. Let's look at e.g. Symbian - it's relatively open too and they have this: forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/8299c7a4-d3d8-4c4c-b62e-97a4c831e6a3/User_Experience_Evaluation_Model_v1_1_en.pdf.html
Great help, good basics!

Apple has this: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html 
Examplary done!

Now I am searching for the equivalent document for Android UI Devs (again, not the programming part). This one looks great: developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html 
but it does not cover all scenarios and sooner or later gets lost in advices for coding.

I'm looking forward to your help.
Many thanks and best regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android user interface guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470566/android-user-interface-guidelines)

Answer (score 3):

I think those at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html are the only ones at the moment, quote: *The Android UI team has begun developing guidelines for the interaction and visual design of Android applications. Look here for articles that describe these guidelines as we release them.*. So it sounds like there will be more in the future but they haven't finished them yet.

You can also find some information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

In general, I don't think Google has a different mindset than Apple when it comes to design so I doubt there will ever be as much official material.

There's a document called *androidhig.pdf* that seems to be someone that has just created a set ot reasonable guidelines themselves by adapting the IPhone ones, I can't find any download link for that document now, but if you google for the file name you can do quickview on at least one of the links to see the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. But it can't be an argument that Googles an Apples mindset are the same. Of course there are guidelines that fit for android as for iOS. But android needs its own and I think it's a little bit poor that the android UI team but now is developing guidelines! Android exists for 2 years now.
Ok, I'll just wait till final guidelines are out. I'm really curious how Google will work it out. Perhaps they wait till gingerbread is out - as I heard, google wants to change the UI completely to make Sense/Touchwiz and sort of things obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Google has launched a brand new site with [Android UI and design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

As @ho1 notes, HIG is very much a work in progress. In addition to those suggestions, I'd recommend a recent blog post on [UI design patterns](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html), which I found enlightening.

EDITED ADDENDUM: UI design patterns were also described at the I/O conference, [available as video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1ZBjlCRfz0).

Comment: This one is really nice. When they got something like that for all ocasions/scenarios it would be perfect.